# How can I do a command depending on where a player is facing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make things that go where a player is facing, for example a PrimedTnt move the direction a player is facing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> @p[rx=#,rxm=#]

to test someone's rotation

Answer (score -1):

You should do some research before answering

[this video will help](https://youtu.be/rYxxb9i7Bxs)

(yeah i actually don't know ;-;)

Comment: Link only answers aren't helpful. Please summarize the steps in the video so that future users looking this up can do this, regardless if the video is there or not. Also, he's asking for a command that moves objects into his line of view, not how to use the rotation selector condition (although that may end up being used).